# Connect SDK seeking jumps to 0:00

Tags: android, chromecast, television

So, I am trying to set up video controls on Android, when I now try to seek to 0:10 on my Chromecast using `mMediaControl.seek(10,null);` it seeks always to 0:00.

However the Logcat shows that the seeking was successfull.

Is this a generall SDK Bug or is it my fault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android Connect SDK uses milliseconds when seeking.  So you have the right call.  Just convert it.

```
mMediaControl.seek(10000, null);
```

Or if you want to keep it in seconds.

```
float mTimeInSeconds = 10.0;
mMediaControl.seek((long) (mTimeInSeconds * 1000), null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't that be:

```
mMediaControl.seek(<yourmApiClient>,10000);
```

[GOO doc on RemoteMediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/RemoteMediaPlayer.html)

```
seek(GoogleApiClient apiClient, long position)
Seeks to a new position within the current media item.
```

Comment: so mMediaControl.seek(<yourmApiClient>,10000); and mMediaControl.seek(10,null); gaved you the same result?

Can you share your log cat?

Comment: mMediaControl.seek(10,null); isn't allowed by eclipse... i think you mean the chromecast sdk, i am using connect sdk, it's a framework